# Rotate element clockwise on page load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, autorotate

I am using [jQuery Rotating Elements](http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-For-Rotating-Elements-Clockwise-or-Counterclockwise-Aperture.html) and it is doing exactly what I'm looking for aside from the fact that the user must click in order for the boxes to rotate. I would like for the boxes to automatically rotate clockwise every x seconds. I'm not going to copy all of the code as it can easily be downloaded for free on the link above and you may see it applied to my site [here](http://www.adroitwebdesign.com/service/category/bankruptcy/alabama/birmingham/).

Inside the jquery.aperture.js file I see

```
    triggerRotation : function($imgBox, $rsRow) {
        $('body')
        .on('click touchstart', '#aperture-rotate-cw:not(.anim-running)', function() {
            var $trigger = $(this);
            $trigger.addClass('anim-running');

            $imgBox
            .stop(true, true)
            .each(function(i) {
                var $thisIb = $(this),
                    leftTo = $thisIb.attr('data-cw-left-to'),
                    topTo = $thisIb.attr('data-cw-top-to');

                $thisIb
                .animate({
                    left : leftTo,
                    top : topTo,
                }, methods.settings.duration, methods.settings.easing, function() {
                });
            })
            .promise()
            .done(function() {
                methods.setTargetPosition($rsRow);
                $trigger.removeClass('anim-running');
            });
        });
```

And I feel like if it was .on('load') instead of .on('click touchstart') I may be in the correct section but I honestly don't know what I need to change to make this happen the way I'd like it to.

Your help is appreciated and I'd be happy to provide additional details if needed.

Comment: I can't be sure but you could try changing 'click touchstart' to 'ready'

Comment: I tried changing it to 'ready' and that did not work. While it may work, there is nothing that states the frequency of rotation.

Comment: You could look into `setInterval(function,timeInterval)`. I've never used it so I can't tell you much about it, but I've heard of it. And it sounds like what you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't entirely sure how to integrate that into the code but between your answer and amb110395's answer I was able to make it work. Thanks you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the setTimeout function like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {

      // Call your rotating function

}, desiredTimeInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: This just about did want I needed it to, but instead of setTimeout(function() { I used setInterval(function(){